# Desc fetch :n rows in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a method that contains query like that

```
public List<Order> getOrders (int customer_id, int count)
{
  String sql= "select * from order where customer_id = ? order by order_id DESC FETCH FIRST ? ROWS 
  ONLY"
}
```

What i want to do is to list orders according to given input(count).I get error like that

```
Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
```

If I remove the second ?  and I write `DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS` it executes succesfully.I think I could not use salary parameter in DESC FETCH statement.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post the other parts of the code as the function you have posted is only the query and you are probably missing something when replacing the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed **no limitation** for `DESC` order in the [order_by_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2168299) and  [row_limiting_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBADDD)

you must somehow *not set the second parameter* ...

Here is working JDBC example with a marked line, that if commented out leads to your exception

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("""select order_id from getOrders 
                                   where customer_id = ? 
                                   order by order_id DESC
                                   FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY""")
stmt.setInt(1,1001)  /* Bind customer_id = 1001 */
stmt.setInt(2,3)  /* bind count of rows = 3; uncomment to get java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2  */

def rs = stmt.executeQuery()

while(rs.next())
  {
   println "order_id= ${rs.getInt(1)}"
  }
```

Comment: I use spring Jdbc not plain jdbc but I will try to change your code to spring jdbc.Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you use JDBCTemplate or Spring Data JDBC? If you have still problems post your full statement.